CA72 can't read ICC_IAR1_EL1 anymore after switch from EL3 to EL1 NS
I can read out ICC_IAR1_EL1 when CA72 at EL3 secure world.
After that, I configure El3 from Secure to Non-secure, after switch EL3 to El2, EL2 to El1.
At the end, I confirm A72 works at EL1 by get_currentEL=0x4. When I try to read ICC_IAR1_EL1 again, unhandled exception happens. why is that? thanks in advance.

__func__011000 EC=MSR, MRS, or System instruction, that isn't reported using EC 0x00/0x01/0x07Unhandled exception 0x18(24) from CA72_0 to  CA72_0
EXC number:0x00000018
EXC class: 0x00000018
FaultReg:  0x00000000
StatusPrg: 0x60000004
PC: 0x00000000 0xA0007F94
                         FaultReg:  0xD538CC80
StatusPrg: 0x00383019
Exception class is MSR_MRS
                          These report exceptions from MSR, MRS, or System instructions
                                                                                       Instruction syndrome MSR/MRS:
                                                                                                                    Op0: 0x00000000
Op2: 0x00000000
Op1: 0x00000000
CRn: 0x00000000
Rt : 0x00000000
CRm: 0x00000018
dir: 0x00000001


More than that, I met same issue when I try to read other ICC_xxxx registers.
